Do solipsism and the theory that the external world is real have equal explanatory value?
Given a recent question just asked in regards to whether or not Occam's razor supports solipsism, I thought it would be prudent to ask whether the explanatory value of both theories (solipsism vs. the external world being real) are equal.
To make things a bit more interesting, let's assume that under a solipsistic theory, our experience follows certain laws, which happen to be the same laws in physics.
Thus, in order to generate our conscious experience, certain laws and initial conditions are all that is needed to predict the forthcoming parts of our subjective experience.
Now, in order to generate the events of the real world under the theory that the external world is real, the same laws and initial conditions are all that is needed to predict the events of the universe.
Thus, can't one argue that the explanatory power of both theories are actually the same, contrary to the notion that solipsism has inferior explanatory power? If someone retorts and asks "what generates our conscious experience in solipsism? It seems to come from nowhere.", the same can be asked for the theory that the external world is real. As far as we know, we do not actually have an explanation for what generates our conscious experience in the traditional, materialistic view of the world.
So again, is there a difference in explanatory value between solipsism and the theory that the external world is real? Or not?
EDIT:
One thing I can think of from a pro materialist view is that it may make no sense for laws to operate on an immaterial reality. What are the laws acting upon if there is no ontological difference between components of experience?

Solipsism - I only know my own experience. Reality - See Solipsism!

Solipsism has no explanatory value at all.

"...under a solipsistic theory, our experience..." -- To talk of "our" experience, "under a solipsistic theory" doesn't really seem to make sense or be self-consistent.

Realism: external world is real, follows laws and affects our sensory organs to generate large part of our experience. Solipsism: everything happens as above, but it is all an illusion secretly generated by deep deep recesses of our own mind that we have no direct knowledge of or voluntary control over. One needs some twisted ideas of simplicity and explanation to credit with them such a conspiracy theory.

@Conifold If I may play devil's advocate here, this answer makes a very good case for solipsism.

Nothing can match solipsism for the universal simplicity of its explanatory power. But we're always also almost always interested in eg. prediction, control. See

@Conifold why are you assuming that the experience in solipsism is generated by something else? Perhaps all reality is is conscious experience, and there is only one experience. This experience then also follows laws the same way the external world does. Due to the hard problem of consciousness, the external world theory doesn’t explain how consciousness is generated anyways. So, again, where is the difference in explanatory power?

The problem is exactly that in solipsism it is not generated by something else. Only one conscious experience as such is not solipsism, "anything that would commonly be regarded as a constituent of the space and time in which I coexist with others is necessarily construed by me as part of the content of my consciousness." It is one thing to suppose that something else is inexplicable to me, it is quite another to suppose that I am inexplicable to myself while being the author of it all.

@Conifold you still seem to be implying that a solipsist is the author of his experience. Just imagine a reality where there is only one conscious experience, whatever that is called. In this experience, the feeling of being a subject is yet another content in consciousness. Everything is part of consciousness. In this field of consciousness, everything also follows the same laws as in realism. Now, where is the difference in explanatory power?

I what sense is this consciousness detached from "feeling of being a subject" still "my" consciousness, or "experience" of anything or at all? Your imagined reality is plain objective idealism with mind/"consciousness" as the fundamental substrate, and if it follows "the same laws" it will have multiple "subject feelings" floating in it, as in Schopenhauer, say. It is as realist as material external world and one can then debate explanatory benefits of idealism vs materialism, but it has nothing to do with solipsism.

It’s not detached @Conifold The feeling of being a subject is a content in consciousness the same way the image of a TV and the floor is. It’s not so much “my” but rather “only”, and there is nothing logically inconsistent here. And neither does this imply multiple subject feelings. It’s one stream of consciousness where the abstractions in that consciousness follow laws. Nothing generates the consciousness. It just is. That combined with the laws acting on the objects in consciousness would be the only brute facts. It’s a video game with a first person POV but without a creator

You cannot have it both ways. Either you have solipsism and this "stream" is mine with vast conspiracy screening me from myself, or you have uncreated law-abiding "consciousness" hosting "subject feeling(s)" among other items and no solipsism.

@Conifold You forgot the third option: uncreated law-abiding consciousness of which there is only one stream of consciousness: the one you experience. The other “subjects” you see aren’t real subjects: they’re figments of imagination that still behave according to laws

'One' or 'many' is just an artifact of the stream metaphor and makes no difference in substance. Your 'one' has no hold over this 'stream' and no clue about most of goings on there, so he is just as 'real' or 'figment' as 'others'. Nobody is there to do the 'imagining' anyway, the 'stream' just 'flows' "according to laws" with all of that inside.

@Conifold There is a clear difference between there being only one stream of consciousness, and multiple streams attached to different subjects. The point is that there is no “he” so there’s no requirement for “him” to have hold over the stream at all. Like I said, the analogy to a video game from a first person POV is good enough. The objects in the video game don’t have their own locuses of consciousness. They are artifacts of the one, and only one, consciousness. Every artifact within that consciousness behaves according to laws. “Nobody” is there to do the imagining, yes, that’s the point.

Except your stream is attached to no subject. The 'real' subject, if any, is one of the 'figments' to which that label is attached by fiat. And the videogame analogy is pretty bad, it obscures the difference between idealism and solipsism entirely.

@Conifold and that is fine. The stream is attached to no subject, that is the very point. It may feel like the stream is attached to a subject, the same way it feels like your POV experience of a video game is attached to a subject. But the feeling of being a subject is yet another content in consciousness. It does not imply the existence of a subject, and there’s no issue with that. The other artifacts, such as other “human looking” people, in your experience may also seem to be in reality over and above the mere sight of them, but there is no need to posit their external reality.

No. What you seem to be suggesting is that you might make an assumption that your individual mental sensations are governed by some set of rules that ensures that the events you, the solipsist, imagine in your head evolve in the same way as events I, the non-solipsist, perceive in the real world. The difference, of course, is that you cannot say what the rules are. I can say what many of the rules are in the real world, and I can see why certain patterns I perceive are the result of other influences. You cannot specify what the corresponding solipsistic rules are- you can only hypothesise that they exist, which is no explanation at all. You might just as well say that an omnipotent invisible pink rabbit is the cause of everything.
Also, the rules that govern the real world only make sense in the context of there being a real word. For example, there are many factors at play that have lead to millions of people communicating in mandarin, a language I do not understand. I would challenge you to provide a convincing explanation of why and how your brain would create the experience of a world in which millions of people seemed to communicate effectively in a language your brain does not appear to understand. Simply assuming that there is some set of rules to account for it is hardly an explanation.
EDIT
Solipsism has no explanatory power in relation to the acquisition of knowledge. In the real world, I experience many things that I do not understand. To take the example in the comments, I experience computers performing rapid calculations that would take me days to perform long-hand. I have no idea how the computer works. I can discover how it works by looking at information produced by other people. More generally, my explanation for how I, in the real world, possess knowledge, is that I have gained it over the course of my life, benefitting from the knowledge of others. I have not studied the algorithms that find the fourth root of a number, for example, but other people have, and I can read what they have written to acquire that knowledge. In my real world view, billions of humans have acquired knowledge and are able to share what they have acquired. How do you, the solipsist, explain that? How can you account for the fact that your mind is able to imagine a computer finding a fourth root of a large number, and yet you have no immediate idea of how it does so? It seems to me that you have to assume that the knowledge is all there in your head to begin with.
You also are suggesting that somehow the laws of physics might just as equally apply to your imagined solipsistic world. But the laws of physics require, for example, the conservation of energy, so how are you, as the solipsist, fuelled? What is your source of energy? Your imagined solipsistic experience is that you consume food. But according to you, the food does not exist.
It seems to me that you are trying to explain your solipsist's imagined world by analogy with my real external world, while denying that my world exists! You can't have it both ways.

"Simply assuming that there is some set of rules to account for it is hardly an explanation." Isn't that exactly what's being done in the real world? Given initial conditions and the laws of physics and assuming that determinism is for the most part true, people communicating in that language was inevitable. Why can't the same exact laws and initial conditions be used in a solipsistic form of reality? Note that I don't actually believe in solipsism but I'm trying to figure out how it explains less. The only thing I can think of is that the rules may not make sense in an immaterial experience

The difference is that the rules make sense in the context of the real world, but not in the context of an imagined one. Take the factoring of a large prime number by a computer. In the real world I can explain the process through which it happens. How can you explain how your brain would imagine the result?

You can represent the different objects in your experience as abstract representations (such as the different components of the computer), and describe that process through those abstractions. What part of this process involves assuming that the external world is real? @Marco Ocram

It doesn't involve that assumption. I am asking you how to reconcile the assumption that on the one hand you are able to correctly imagine the prime factors of a very large number, when on the other hand you also have a conscious experience of not being able to imagine them.

Suppose I asked you to calculate the cube root of the number 943823972543 in your head in two seconds. Can you do it? I assume not. So how do you reconcile that with the view that as a solipsist you can correctly imagine the cube root displayed in an imagined cell in an imagined spreadsheet?

What explanation of the calculation does solipsism provide?

If my solipsistic experience is occurring according to laws, then the experience of seeing the result of a square root would only occur if those same laws are followed. In this case, one would have to use a computer to solve it, except that the computer would only be an abstraction in your head. I’m still confused as to what part of this process is better explained by the existence of an external world.

But how does your mental computer work? How does solipsism explain it?

It works according to the same laws defined in physics. The laws just operate on abstractions in experience instead of real objects external to those abstractions @Marco Ocram

@MarcoOcram for a solipsist necessarily accept the premise that there is such a thing as a "correct" cube root? Or as "two seconds"?

@syed but that is not an explanation! You are simply saying there is some explanation that you don't understand, and your explanation is the same as that, whatever that is. I am asking you to spell out how a computer performs a calculation according to solipsism. You claim that solipsism has equal explanatory power. So please demonstrate it. Please demonstrate how the assumption that everything is just imagined in your head leads to the production of the correct result of a calculation that would take you hours to perform long-hand.

@DarkMalthorp who knows, but the claim being made here is that solipsism has equal explanatory power. Presumably that means equal power to explain how a computer finds the correct cube root.

@MarcoOcram Spell out how a computer performs that calculation in the external world. Presumably, this would involve inputs and circuits following the laws of physics. The same exact explanation would be for solipsism but for every object replace it with an abstraction of the object.

Again, you are simply not providing the explanation. Tell me what it is. You are the solipsist. The outside world does not exist for you. How can I tell you how a computer works in the 'external world' if there isn't one and if I do not exist? You are assuming that an outside world exists in order to give you a model for your solipsistic equivalent!!!

You are claiming that solipsism has equal explanatory power. That means that you must be able to explain all of the things you experience - such as computers performing a calculation- without reference to the existence of an external world. I have asked you to give me an explanation on that basis- ie, without reference to the existence of an external world, explain to me how you can experience a computer finding a cube root of a large number.

See my edit....

I consider neither solipsism nor the existence of an external world a theory. Both are hypotheses.
The latter is the basic hypothesis of science and also of our everyday understanding and acting. The former is the principle of a different worldview which may possibly be used to question science.
Science strives with some success to build a consistent theory which explains observations in different domains. But I have never met a proponent of solipsism who acts accordingly to their thesis. Hence solipsism lacks any consequence in action.

In this answer, I’ll restate the comparison made in this chat discussion:
Option 1: Physicalism
Brute Facts

Spacetime (and potentially several more dimensions)
Physical laws
Physical constants
A huge amount of elementary particles
Possible existence of a multiverse
Anything else I'm probably forgetting.

Explanation of First-Person Experience under Physicalism
The explanation of first-person experience in physicalism is complex, especially due to the Hard Problem of Consciousness. Nevertheless, if we assume consciousness somehow emerges from matter (as posited by theories like type physicalism), subjective experience is explained as signals from the external world that are decoded and interpreted by the observer’s brain, changing in accordance with physical laws over time.

Option 2: Metaphysical Solipsism (as suggested in chat)
Brute Facts

This mind
The present moment (with time as an illusion; only the present exists)
Present experience of memories creating the illusion of time
The contents of this mind (i.e., qualia) in the present moment

Explanation of First-Person Experience under Metaphysical Solipsism
Here, all conscious experiences are simply brute facts experienced by this mind in the present moment.

Comparing the Two Worldviews
Both physicalism and metaphysical solipsism posit brute facts that resist further reduction. However, the version of metaphysical solipsism I suggest requires only a minimal set of brute facts to account for subjective experience in the present, where the past and future are illusory. Physicalism, by contrast, requires a more elaborate framework, including physical laws, fundamental particles, spacetime, and possibly multiple dimensions or universes.
In terms of explanatory power, both worldviews can more or less explain (or explain away) first-person subjective experiences, albeit with differing degrees of ontological complexity.

Whether or not the present moment is all that exists, you can atleast acknowledge that there is a variety of different experiences, even if it's only in your memory as an illusion. Either way, what explains why those experiences occur instead of others? You can classify this as "one" brute fact but it remains unexplained as to why those memories exhibit a pattern. One way to resolve this is to admit that laws still operate in a solipsistic world, except that they only operate on abstractions, and not real objects themselves. But does this seem plausible? I would have to think more about this

@Syed Postulating laws to explain the existence of apparent patterns in memories in the present moment would not solve the problem, because now you have to explain why those laws and not other laws. And if you postulate the laws as brute facts, why not save one step and just postulate the memories as brute facts?

@Syed You may also want to read this answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/118464/80226

because the law simplifies the data. It compresses it

You ask:

Do solipsism and the theory that the external world is real have equal explanatory value?

Absolutely not. The theory that the external world is real has a name in modern discourse: scientific realism (SEP). Scientific realism is an extension of direct realism and takes human intuitions about reality and layers them with the sciences. The end result is that the modern scientific project explains a tremendous variety of phenomena, from the formal sciences which are mathematical and logical in nature, to the natural sciences, which describe physical, chemical, and biological objects and events. The social sciences explain minds and societies, imperfectly, but to a great extent. Solipsism, on the hand, is a minor hiccup in insights that direct realism has to contend with scientific instrumentalism, and that there is a difference between appearances and actuality. Sophisticated thinkers tend to contemplate solipsism in the same way as radical skepticism, and then reject it wholeheartedly as a philosophical dead end.


Do solipsism and the theory that the external world is real have equal explanatory value?

If solipsism is the belief that your own mind is the only reality, then the only thing to explain is your own mind.
Scientific explanations all involve entities distinct from anybody's mind, so a solipsist in this sense cannot completely accept any scientific theory. However, a solipsist could accept the form of scientific theories while rejecting their underlying ontology. The solipsist could for example take quarks and magnetic fields not as part of a physical world (which the solipsist in this sense believes doesn't exist), but as part of his or her own mind.
The explanatory power of such a theory would be strictly identical to that of science, but only for the solipsist, not of course for other people, who by definition literally know that the solipsist's theory is false. False theories have zero explanatory power.
If solipsism is the theory that one's mind is the only thing that we know, then the belief in this theory makes zero difference in terms of the explanatory power of scientific theories. However, solipsism in this sense does not say that the external world is not real. It says that we can only have beliefs about it, not knowledge. Notice that scientists nowadays only claim that scientific theories have a predictive power, not that they are necessarily true of the real world.
